# How to install Sublime Text 3 on elementary OS?

Tags: software-installation

Is there an easy way to install [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) 3 using `apt-get` on elementary OS?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There isn’t an official PPA, but you can use webupd8's PPA.

Just try this on your terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Also you can download the `.deb` file from http://www.sublimetext.com/3 and install it.

Comment: You could also simply download the .deb here: http://www.sublimetext.com/3